# Why I can't show snackbar using a global scaffold key after dispose?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have a global key assigned to the top level scaffold in my app:

```dart
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> globalScaffoldKey = GlobalKey();
```

I assign it like this:

```dart
             MaterialApp.router(
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              routerConfig: appRouter,
              builder: (context, child) {
                return Container(
                    child: Scaffold(
                      key: globalScaffoldKey,
                      body: ...
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
```

Then in one of the screens below the material app, I have this code:

```
                      doSomeAsyncWork(
                        onSuccess: () {
                          showSuccessSnackBar(
                            context: globalScaffoldKey.currentContext!,
                            text: AppLocalizations.of(context)!
                                .profileUpdatedSuccessfully,
                          );
                          if(!mounted) return;
                          GoRouter.of(context).pop();
                        },
                      );
```

If I go back from that screen before the onSuccess has been called (it is called from inside doAsyncWork), then when its called, I get this error: This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered defunct

I know it means that the globalScaffoldKey.currentContext! is being considered not mounted, but my question is why? That scaffold is above both the screen I was in and the screen I navigated to.

note: - showSuccessSnackBar just calls the built-in ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar:

```dart
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).clearSnackBars();
  return ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
...
```

I even tried calling the showSnackBar method from the dispose of this screen after 2 seconds:

```dart
  @override
  void dispose() {

     ...

    Future.delayed(
      Duration(seconds: 2),
      () {
        print('after 2 seconds of disposing profile screen');
        print('is screen mounted: $mounted');
        print('is global scaffold key mounted: ${globalScaffoldKey.currentContext!.mounted}');
        return showSuccessSnackBar(
        context: globalScaffoldKey.currentContext!,
        text: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.profileUpdatedSuccessfully,
      );
      },
    );
```

I got this output (and the same error)

```
flutter: is screen mounted: false
flutter: is global scaffold key mounted: true
```